# How can I kick players from the player list? (socket.io)

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

I am providing an environment for users by using socket io in my Vue based game project. I want users in the lobby to be kicked by the admin. In the codes below, the admin just kicks yourself from the room no matter which player clicks on it. I want the player it clicked on to be kicked out of the room. Sorry for my bad english. I hope I could explain.

**Playerlist.vue**

```
    <template>
    <h2 class="team-head">{{ teamNumber }}. TEAM</h2>
    <ol role="player-list">
      <li v-for="(member, index) of members" :key="Object.keys(member)[0]" style="--li-bg: purple">
       <b>
        <a @click="kickUser(Object.keys(member)[0])">{{ member[Object.keys(member)[0]] }}</a>
        <i style="font-size: 20px;" v-if="Object.keys(member)[0] === roomLeader" class="fas fa-crown"></i>
        <i style="display:none;font-size: 20px;" :class="{'ben': checkIfMe(Object.keys(member)[0]),isTelling: isTelling(index),}" class="fas fa-star"></i>
      </b>
     </li>
    </ol>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      props: ["members", "teamNumber", "isMyTeamsTurn", "tellerTurn", "roomLeader"],
      inject: ["socket"],
      methods: {
        checkIfMe(key) {
          if (this.socket.id === key) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        },
        isTelling(myIndex) {
          return this.isMyTeamsTurn && this.tellerTurn === myIndex;
        },
       kickUser(player) {
       this.socket.emit('forceDisconnect', player);
       },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**Server.js** (Socket io)

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => { 
...
   socket.on('forceDisconnect', function(player){
  console.log("Disconnected Socket = " + player);
  //socket.disconnect();
   });
...
});
```